# Sort string array by first part of each element in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I have a string array like:

```
String[] strengths = new String[] {"0.5 G", "0.8 G", "1 G", "1.6 G", "2.5 G", "5 G", "10 G", "12.5 G", "20 G", "25 G", "30 G"}
```

If I use the default sort

```
Arrays.sort(strengths)
```

it will sort the elements as numbers, but I would like to sort it based on the number in ascending order.
I try to use a comparator

```
Arrays.sort(strengths, new Comparator<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                       try {
                           String[] obj1 = o1.split(" ");
                            String[] obj2 = o2.split(" ");
                            float number1= Float.parseFloat(obj1[0]);
                            float number2= Float.parseFloat(obj2[0]);
                            if ( number1< number2) {return 1;} 
                             else {return -1;}
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                         return 0;

                                                }



                    }
                });
```

but it does not seems to work...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No effort on your part = downvotes, in case you are wondering.  If you post some code, you'll get better responses.

Comment: This is no different than sorting any normal array. All you have to do first is split up the `String` into the `int` and a `String` array (probably with a class). Then sort based on the `int`.

Comment: Nice question. Now did you try something?

Comment: It will depend upon how you can construct your string, if you can convert it into either grams or mg, then it will be quite straight forward .. So, you need to tell what all you can do and what all you cannot do ..

Comment: Yes, there are easy ways of doing it.

Comment: :) Ok, I admit, I was lazy... Could I get some help with the actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the comparator, and then, the Float Comparator:

```
   Arrays.sort(strengths, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return Float.compare(Float.valueOf(o1.split(" ")[0]), Float.valueOf(o2.split(" ")[0]));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a comparator.

In the comparator code you can simply split the corresponding two strings and return the comparison value based on the integer part only.

Comment: Can you post your code. I can try and guide you through it.

Comment: You forgot the 0 case, but you are best off using the answer offered by @David Perez.